# React Query - use cache for manually triggered refetch

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm working on a hook that handles queries in a que.

In order to achieve this I'm using the `refetch` from the queries and calling them in an order.

The issue that I'm facing is that if I'm calling the queries more than one time(because of re-renders), keys are the same and everything, it does an API call every time. I think this is because of the `refetch` itself, as it's manually triggered.

Is there some method of setting the `refetch` to use the data from cache if there is some?

As a working example of what I'm trying to achieve please take a look over this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-river-o6kr77?file=/src/index.js)

In the sandbox, the refetch is executed in the `useEffect` every 5 seconds and in the network inspection tab we can actually see the call been executed even if the key is the same and everything... Can this be prevented? Is there some option that can be set to use the cache if there is any?

I'm using react-query V3, below is the code example from the sandbox.

```js
function Example() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(1);
  const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery(
    "repoData",
    () =>
      axios
        .get("https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query")
        .then((res) => res.data)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // HERE THIS SHOULD LOAD DATA FROM CACHE IF THERE IS SOME NOT FIRE A NEW CALL
    refetch();

    setTimeout(() => {
      setX((prevState) => prevState + 1);
    }, 5000);
  }, [x, setX, refetch]);

  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";

  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.description}</p>
      <strong> {data.subscribers_count}</strong>{" "}
      <strong>✨ {data.stargazers_count}</strong>{" "}
      <strong> {data.forks_count}</strong>
      <div>{isFetching ? "Updating..." : ""}</div>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it's hard to answer without knowing what you are trying to achieve with that. solutions that include refetch in a useEffect are usually not advised, so maybe if you'd show the actual problem you're trying to solve, we could come to a completely different solution ...

Comment: @TkDodo - I'm trying to achieve a que system for queries. We have some pages where we list some tiles that contains some graph component (may be 100+). For these the API calls should be done one by one. I managed to create this que system and call the `refetch` on the current item, get it out of the que. Currently for the issue with refetching I've implemented a `cacheKey` prop on every que item and store it. If the params and key are the same, it will not refetch it. It works fine. I was curious if there was some simple way of just making the refetch itself aware of the queryClient cache

Comment: `queryClient.fetchQuery({ queryKey, queryFn, staleTime })` will read from the cache if there is data in the cache that isn't older than staleTime. `queryClient.ensureQueryData` will not fetch if there is any data in the cache.